# Groovy HTMLUnit Error - Caught: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser.parseMedia

Tags: groovy, htmlunit

I am getting this error in a groovy script:

> Caught: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser.parseMedia(Lorg/w3c/css/sac/InputSource;)Lorg/w3c/css/sac/SACMediaList;
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser.parseMedia(Lorg/w3c/css/sac/InputSource;)Lorg/w3c/css/sac/SACMediaList;
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.parseMedia(CSSStyleSheet.java:937)

My **grapes** are as follows:

```
@Grapes([
@Grab(group='commons-io', module='commons-io', version='2.4'),
@Grab(group='net.sourceforge.htmlunit', module='htmlunit', version='2.19'),
@Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.7.16'),
@Grab(group='log4j', module='log4j', version='1.2.17'),
@Grab(group='javax.mail', module='mail', version='1.4'),
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-email', version='1.4'),
@GrabExclude('xml-apis:xml-apis')
])
```

Any idea why this error is happening?

Comment: Because you're telling it to exclude `@GrabExclude('net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser')`?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't supposed to be in there. It was originally in there to see if there was a conflict